# Como eu retiro a String de dentro de um retorno do Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, array, sequelize-js

Eu fiz um select pelo Sequelize e ele me trás isso:

```
[
    TextRow { permission: 'group.default' },
    TextRow { permission: 'group.fundador' }
]
```

Porém como eu pego somente o `'group.#'` desse array? Quero algo como:

```
['group.default', 'group.fundador']
```

Meu código até agora:

```js
const groupsmess = await GroupsSelect(useruuiddb.uuid)
console.log(groupsmess[0])
```

Comment: Já tentou, por exemplo, `groupsmess[0].permission`?

Comment: Sim porém isso só me trás o resultado de uma array especifica, exemplo: groupsmes[1].permission, porém isso vem de um banco de dados e esse numero de arrays geradas pode ser infinito exemplo:groupsmes[1].permission, groupsmes[2].permission, groupsmes[3].permission.....

Comment: E o que você deseja fazer exatamente?

Comment: Eu quero só ler os dados que o meu banco de dados trás, esse TextRow é cada coluna, e eu não tenho um limite para isso, por isso não posso usar o [numero da array]

Comment: Eu entendi isso, mas você pode fazer infinitas coisas com a informação que deu na pergunta. É  importante que você detalhe um pouco melhor para que possamos ajudá-la. Você quer, por exemplo, imprimir cada elemento? Quer usar cada elemento para criar uma lista de valores? Em suma, infinitas possibilidades até que tenhamos uma descrição um pouco mais específica. :)

Comment: Esses elementos são coisas que eu tenho que comprar, porém eu não posso simplesmente pegar a [0] === comparação, por que eu não sei em qual posição o banco iria me trazer a array, se fossem números eu poderia usar uma organização, porém são strings.

Comment: Resumindo eu teria que fazer de uma forma geral, exemplo se: Se a informação tiver A, B, C então eu faço F, G, D. Porém isso tem que ser de uma forma global não especifica.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar um [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) para iterar sobre os valores? Ou talvez [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)? Porque como é um array, você precisa, em tese, trabalhar sobre cada valor já que não sabe qual escolher. Aí pode fazer uma comparação (ou alguma lógica qualquer) em cada iteração. Eu não conseguirei ajudar mais que isso sem ter mais detalhes. Não sei o que significa `A`, `B`, `C`, `F`, `G` ou `D`. Você precisa detalhar melhor.

Comment: Não tentei usar o For. Resumindo a array me trás isso: [ TextRow { permission: 'group.default' }, TextRow { permission: 'group.fundador' } ], eu preciso que isso se transforme em uma array só contendo o 'group.<perm>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note que você tem um array e quer *mapear* cada elemento do array original em alguma outra coisa. Isso irá, então, gerar um array de mesmo comprimento que o original.

Nesse tipo de situação, o mais ideal é utilizar o método [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para *mapear* cada elemento do array original em alguma outra coisa. Leia a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para entender como o `map` funciona a fundo.

No seu caso, como quer mapear o array de objetos para somente uma das propriedades do objeto (no caso, `permission`), ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```js
const permissions = groupsmess.map((group) => group.permission);
```

Note que o `map` é, em síntese, uma função aplicada para cada elemento do array. No caso, para cada elemento de `groupmess`, estamos aplicando a função que retorna a propriedade `permission` do elemento da iteração em questão.

Um exemplo no *browser*:

```js
const data = [
  { permission: 'group.default' },
  { permission: 'group.fundador' }
];

const permissions = data.map((object) => object.permission);

console.log(permissions);
```

Uma outra alternativa seria criar o array e mapear cada elemento explicitamente utilizando um `for`. Mais ou menos assim:

```js
const data = [
  { permission: 'group.default' },
  { permission: 'group.fundador' }
];

// Criamos um novo array:
const permissions = [];

// Percorremos sobre cada objeto do array original:
for (const object of data) {
  // A cada iteração inserimos `object.permission` no novo array:
  permissions.push(object.permission);
}

// Mesma saída:
console.log(permissions);
```